# 'list' object has no attribute 'strptime'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, strptime

Here I want to read time in 24 hours format include in csv file. I wrote the class to convert time in format `%H:%M:%S`. but I got an error

> 'list' object has no attribute 'strptime'

Can anyone help to solve this? Here I post my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import datetime

def convertTime(s):
    tm = time.strptime(s, "%H:%M:%S")
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec)

data = pd.read_csv('x.csv')
row_num = 0
for row in data:
    if(row_num == 0):
    time.append(convertTime(row[0]))
```

Here  is subset of my csv file

```
time         g
6:15:00   141
9:00:00   0
9:25:00   95
9:30:00   0
11:00:00  149
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @akilat90 I want read my time in this format.  as an example 6:15:00 in format %H:%M:%S

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear. 6:15:00 is already in %H:%M:%S format, isn't it?

Comment: @akilat90 Sorry I just put only time column. I edit my question. Here I want to plot graph time with g. to do plot I want to call time in this format. But I can't read it in this format. That's why I tried to convert time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this achieve what you want?

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)

# plotting
df.plot()
```

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere in your code (or on the command line) you created a global list `time` (see `time.append(...)`). This list shadows the module `time` that you intended to use in your function. In other words: `time` is a list. Give that list another name.